# where to download locale language

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, language-package

for the CE Magento 1.9.1.0 where to download the locale language of Germany,France and other language? Are there the official language packs?

Answer (score 0):

yes. here you can find all available language pack in magento commerce site and its official from magento community

go to [http://www.magentocommerce.com/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html?utm_source=mc&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=translations)

i am sure you will find all you need.

hope this work for you.